# Get the value of the app service plan using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-group

I am trying to get the only name value of the app service plans using Powershell.

Query :

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "entaddinqagrouptwm" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverfarms | ft
```

The Output is :

```
Name                       ResourceGroupName  ResourceType              Location
----                       -----------------  ------------              --------
ntaddinqaapptwmeastusplan1 entaddinqagrouptwm Microsoft.Web/serverFarms eastus
ntaddinqaapptwmeastusplan2 entaddinqagrouptwm Microsoft.Web/serverFarms eastus
```

My Code :

```
$resourceHash = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "entaddinqagrouptwm" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverfarms | ft
Write-Host "Apps : " $resourceHash.GetValue(0)
```

The result I am getting :

```
Apps :  Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
```

The result I want :

```
ntaddinqaapptwmeastusplan1
ntaddinqaapptwmeastusplan2
```

So that I can use for each loop on the result and perform operation one by one on each app plan.

Comment: Do not pipe to `format-*` commands like `ft` (aka `format-table`) if you want to do further processing including retrieving the object and its properties. Those should be for display purposes only. You should assign `$resourceHash` without the `| ft`. If you want to display a table later in the console, then simply use `$resourceHash | ft`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code below is what you need. No need to "format list". You just need to properly select the property on the $resourceHash object.

```
    $resourceHash = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "entaddinqagrouptwm" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverfarms
    Write-Host "Apps : " $resourceHash.Name
```